# how to get file Icons in a custom QuickOpenItem dropdown?

Tags: vscode-extensions

Working on an extension and one of the features is a custom dropdown for files. It works fine except the fact that I can't get the icons simiarly to vscode ctrl/cmd+p dropdown.

I understand I can use static icon i.e `vscode-icon` this way

```
return `$(vscode-icon) ${f.label}`;
```

But can I do some detection and load the respective icon from the current icon pack?